# mvc base controller class is null in another controller

Tags: model-view-controller

I created a basecontroller in mvc that look like this..

```
    public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDataRepository _repo = new DataRepository();
    public Core.User user;

    protected BaseController()
    {
        var user = _repo.GetUser(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
    }

}
```

I can see that the user gets its data but when I try to use the user class on another controller its null, what am I doing wrong here?

```
    public class DashBoardController : BaseController
{

    // GET: Overview
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a new `user` variable inside the `BaseController` constructor;

Just remove the `var` keyword.

Also, you can make `user` variable `protected`.